# how to interpret string using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I am using a data string on which interpretation needs to be done to get the key value as "45dB typical, 48 dB max" from "LpA: 45dB typical, 48 dB max".I tried using my below code but got the different string.

I tried solving problem using regular expression pattern `'(.*)LpA:(\w*)\n`

```
data_str="""With AC power supply (with 24 PoE+ ports loaded for C9300 SKUs)
●  LpA: 45dB typical, 48 dB max
●  LwA: 5.6B typical, 5.9B max
With AC power supply (with half the number of PoE+ ports loaded for C9300L SKUs)
●  LpA: 44dB typical, 47 dB max
●  LwA: 5.5B typical, 5.8B max
Typical: Noise emission for a typical configuration
Maximum: Statistical maximum to account for variation in production"""

pattern_type=re.compile('(.*)LpA:(\w*)\n',re.I)
key = pattern_type.sub(r"\2","%r"%data_str)
print(key)
```

I expect: 
'''45dB typical, 48 dB max''' 

but out put getting is: 
 
'''45dB typical, 48 dB max
●  LwA: 5.6B typical, 5.9B max
With AC power supply (with half the number of PoE+ ports loaded for C9300L SKUs)
●  LpA: 44dB typical, 47 dB max
●  LwA: 5.5B typical, 5.8B max
Typical: Noise emission for a typical configuration
Maximum: Statistical maximum to account for variation in production'''

Comment: `.sub()` *replaces* the matched part of the string; the rest of the string is passed through unchanged.  You probably want `.search()` instead, or perhaps `.findall()`.

Comment: You have a space after `LpA` but `\w*` will never match anything beginning with a space character.

Comment: for 0 occurrence of  '\w ' it will match \s,I think so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you try to match the entire string and then substitute it with one of the matching groups. Instead, just use `re.search` to *get* that one matching group. Also, you probably want to use `.` instead of `\w` as the substring contains spaces and other non-word characters.

```
>>> pattern_type = re.compile('LpA: (.*)')
>>> key = pattern_type.search(data_str)
>>> key.group(1)
45dB typical, 48 dB max
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a **Positive Lookbehind**:

```
(?<=LpA: ).+$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LFSyBp/1)

Explanation:

```
(?<=LpA: )   Assert that matching LpA, but do not capture in final match
.+           Capture any character
$            Till end of line
```

Code snippet:

```
regex = re.compile("(?<=LpA: ).+$", re.M)
for match in regex.findall(*your_string_here*):
    print(match)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
res = re.search('LpA:(.*)\n', data_str)
if res: #if res is not None
    key = res.group(1).strip()
    print(key)
```

Comment: If you are doing `search`, then you don't really need to start off or end your regex with `.*`, do you? Those *might* be necessary for `match`.

Comment: Now, what does `re.search()` return? Is it something you can call `strip()` on?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add `.group(1)` to return the string

Answer (score 1):

The code below works fine. I also provided you some comment on the regex pattern used.

```
import re

data_str="""With AC power supply (with 24 PoE+ ports loaded for C9300 SKUs)
●  LpA: 45dB typical, 48 dB max
●  LwA: 5.6B typical, 5.9B max
With AC power supply (with half the number of PoE+ ports loaded for C9300L SKUs)
●  LpA: 44dB typical, 47 dB max
●  LwA: 5.5B typical, 5.8B max
Typical: Noise emission for a typical configuration
Maximum: Statistical maximum to account for variation in production"""


# LpA:\s+([^\n]+)\n
# 
# Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn’t match line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks; Regex syntax only
# 
# Match the character string “LpA:” literally (case insensitive) «LpA:»
# Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) «\s+»
#    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
# Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([^\n]+)»
#    Match any character that is NOT the line feed character «[^\n]+»
#       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
# Match the line feed character «\n»
regex = re.compile(r"LpA:\s+([^\n]+)\n", re.I)

for match in regex.findall(data_str):
    print(match)
```

The output I get is the following

```
45dB typical, 48 dB max
44dB typical, 47 dB max
```